# Отображение контента JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код, который позволяет при нажатии на элемент отображать содержимое другой страницы в блоке текущей страницы. Все работает прекрасно, но я хотел бы, что бы отображение было автоматически включено при переходе на эту страницу (то есть что бы первый элемент (активный по умолчанию) отображал информацию без нажатия на элемент). Может изъяснился криво, но, думаю, поймете меня)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $('#ever').click(function(){  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "everything.html",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#everything").html(html);
            }  
        });  
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вызови эту ф-ю после загрузки страницы:

```
var ajaxLoad = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "everything.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#everything").html(html);
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ever').click(ajaxLoad);
    ajaxLoad();
});
```